# How to archive data with google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to writing scripts and am attempting to get started on archiving my data. Right now I have this script, which I thought was a good start, but am getting an error when I attempt to run it.

On the sheet named "Allergen Planner" I have a live CSS feed in cell N17 which updates every hour. I am attempting to archive that data once daily and place it in a new sheet called "Archived data". I've tried looking into researching on my own for some time now, but am struggling to find something that can help. Everything I've found is way above my capabilities. Is there anything I can edit in my script which would achieve what I'm looking for? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
{

var ssA = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ji3Q02uOyrDXyrl7LcghWLcLjz-CeSUgSCU7QD0BVEk');
var sheetA = ssA.getSheetByName('Allergen Planner');
var dataToMove = sheetA.getRange(14,17,sheetA.getLastRow(),sheetA.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var ssB = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ji3Q02uOyrDXyrl7LcghWLcLjz-CeSUgSCU7QD0BVEk'); 
var sheetB = ssB.getSheetByName('Archived Data');
dataToMove.forEach(function(elts){
sheetB.appendRow(elts)
});


}
```

Comment: Can you find out how to check if a sheet with a given name (like "Archived data") exists? how to create a new sheet with a given name, in case it doesn't exist? how to read the contents of one cell and write them to another cell? If so, then you have just about everything you need in order to achieve your aim.

Comment: I don't, but I think the "unknown error occurred" message I'm receiving is a google issue. The other scripts I have which historically work are getting the same issue. So this might work! I just have no way of knowing at the moment.

Comment: Somehow I missed that you posted a code sample where you were trying to do just what I suggested. Sorry about that. For this error, though, can you please edit your post to include the full error message & any stack trace, and show what line it's occurring on?

Comment: I closed the script app and reopened it. What was happening in the execution log was a red-colored "Unkown error occurred" message would appear after I tried to run it. But it works now! so it seems I was able to get it right and I just needed to reboot the app. Thanks for taking the time to comment, however.

Answer (score 1):

The code pasted above worked. If you receive a red "Unkown error occurred" message in the execution log, reboot the script app and try again.